# Composer " The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded"

Tags: magento2, composer, ubuntu, linux

I'm using a mac, virtualbox with a bridged connection and Ubuntu server 20.04. I'm following this tutorial to install Magento 2 on this server. https://websiteforstudents.com/install-magento-2-on-ubuntu-20-04-18-04-with-nginx-and-lets-encrypt/

I can find a lot of people with this issue, but non of their answers seem to resolve this issue.

Does someone have experience working with virtualbox and linux server?

```
sudo composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento
```

Generates this error:

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Creating a "magento/project-community-edition" project at "./magento"
Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.3.5-p1)
  - Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.3.5-p1): Loading from cache
Created project in /var/www/shop/magento
Loading composer repositories with package information

                                                                               
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded  
  : failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

Comment: check this link --- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html#get-the-metapackage

Comment: @MohitPatel  composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition ubuntu. This command gives exactly the same error.

Comment: above link check and read this section `Prerequisites`

Comment: Try this
`composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org` 
Answered here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996782/how-to-correct-the-composer-downloader-transportexception-error-for-composer